# cv.h not found in fedora 15 install of opencv and highgui

Tags: fedora, compile, make, c++, opencv

I'm writing object tracking software in C++ and using OpenCV and highgui. The problem I have right now is that even after `sudo yum install opencv` and using the `yumex` frontend to *ensure* that all of the packages were installed, `cv.h` is not found when I try to compile.

I looked in `/usr/include/` and there's no trace of `opencv`. What's going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install the -devel packages?

Redhat/Fedora splits software into both runtime (which is what you probably have installed) and developer (headers, static libs) packages. It names these developer packages PACKAGENAME-devel.

Check your install, see if you can install the necessary opencv-devel package(s).

Comment: I installed `opencv-devel` and still get this error.

Comment: @tekknolagi did you verify if the files are around? try: `rpm -q --filesbypkg opencv-devel` and see where it put the files

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1iN32EHL

Comment: @tekknolagi so it installed it, but not directly in /usr/include. You need to adjust your build to pick up the location, -I/usr/include/opencv